# Pascal Ackermann function misunderstood

Tags: pascal

```
function a(m, n:integer):integer
begin
if m = 0 then a := n + 1 ;
if n = 0 then 
    a := a(m-1, 1)
else
    a := a(m-1, a(m, n-1));
end;
```

I can't figure out why this function does not working. I made some test and everything crashes when it get's to `a(0-1, a(0,1-1))` but it this means it comes from `a(0,1)` ... this `a(0,1)` should go with the first if `if m = 0 then a := n +1;` but it goes with the `else` case instead.

Comment: This can only mean that `n != 0` lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that the second `if` is only executed when the first one fails, but nothing in your code indicates that is what should happen.

Comment: Thus `if m = 0 then a := n + 1 else ...`